# how to exit if fail to load file in PHP

Tags: php, xml, exit

I have a PHP script which loads the compressed XML files located locally on the disk. If the XML syntax is fine, the XML is loaded and further operations takes place. However, when the XML file syntax is wrong the script generates warning . I want the script to exit if it can't load the XML file WITHOUT generating any warning. Please help! 
Thanks in advance.

```
       $xml = simplexml_load_file("compress.zlib://local.xml.gz");
        if ($xml=== false)
        {
         echo "Failed loading XML\n";
         foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) 
        {
         echo "\t", $error->message;
        }
        exit(0);
     }

     else 
     {
        echo "Success!Xml File is loaded <br/><br/>";        
     }
```

In my code, the script is exiting but with warnings on the line where the XML file is loaded.

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', '0');`

Comment: @AbraCadaver though it's a solution but as there is a function available to instruct this particular method to generate warning, i believe the best thing would be to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Add a call to `libxml_use_internal_errors` before loading the xml file. Here is the snippet :

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$xml = simplexml_load_file("compress.zlib://local.xml.gz");
```

This will ***Disable libxml errors and allow user to fetch error information as needed***. You can find more info in [php doc](https://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into trying something like this?

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

if (file_exists('compress.zlib://local.xml.gz')) {
  $xml = simplexml_load_file('compress.zlib://local.xml.gz');

  if ($xml === false) {
    echo "Failed loading XML";

    foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
      echo "\t", $error->message;
    }
  } else {
    echo "Success! XML file is loaded <br/><br/>";
  }
} else {
  echo "XML does not exist";      
}
```